# Should [character-development] be a synonym for [character]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Do we need separate tags for [character-development](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-development) and plain ol' [character](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character)? Can we define a simple, meaningful, and useful distinction between the two?

If not, I suggest we synonymize 'em up good.